# Serialise System.Action with JsonUtility.ToJson in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, action

I have a class that simply contains a System.Action delegate :

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class EnvironmentAction
{

    [SerializeField]
    private System.Action _actionToDoNoParameters;


    public EnvironmentAction(System.Action actionToDo)
    {
        _actionToDoNoParameters = actionToDo;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _actionToDoNoParameters();
    }
}
```

I'd like to serialize this into a Json file using `JsonUtility.ToJson()`.

```
private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    Debug.Log("on application quit");

    string jsontest = JsonUtility.ToJson(_environmentAction);
    File.WriteAllText(@".\test_unique_environment_action.json", jsontest);
}
```

I checked by debugging with VS and just before calling `JsonUtility.ToJson()`,
the environmentAction object exists:

[image]

I don't have any issues with other type of fields, including Dictionaries, by implementing ISerializationCallbackReceiver, but I have no idea how to proceed with Actions.

How can I serialize actions? (And even better if you know, how to deserialize them properly?)

Comment: No it can not ... Action isn't serializable in any serializer I know .. what would you expect to printed to the JSON? And what should happen when the JSON is deserialized again? How would you expect the serializer create the correct instance of the action referring to the correct instance of the class and method?

Comment: What is your actual goal with this?